# Connection refused [Tarantool + java client]

Tags: java, sockets, docker, kotlin, tarantool

When i'm trying to connect to tarantool server i get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: connect  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)   at
>   TarantoolKt.main(Tarantool.kt:37)

My code:

```
class Tarantool {
    val client: TarantoolClient

    init {
        val config: TarantoolClientConfig = TarantoolClientConfig()
        config.apply {
            username = "test"
            password = "test"
        }

        val socketChannelProvider: SocketChannelProvider = SocketChannelProvider { _, p1 ->
            when(p1) {
                null -> {
                    println("Trying to connect . . .")
                    SocketChannel.open(InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.254", 3301)) // <- error
                }
                else -> {
                    p1.printStackTrace(System.out)
                    null!!
                }
            }
        }

        client = TarantoolClientImpl(socketChannelProvider, config)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {    
    val client: Tarantool = Tarantool()
    println(client.client.isAlive)
}
```

I get the same error when i'm trying to use different ip

It's the same as in tutorial here: https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java/

I'd also created the test user using this commands:

```
box.schema.user.create('test', { password = 'test' })
box.schema.user.grant('test', 'execute,read,write', 'universe')
```

I use docker for tarantool and i tried to ping IPs from windows 7 cmd and it works.

Thank you!

**SOLVED**

Comment: Can you check if you are able to `telnet 192.168.1.254 3301` from inside the container?

Comment: No, i get error even inside container.

Comment: I assume your are using DockerToolbox?

Comment: Yes, DockerToolBox for windows.
I also tried to connect using container's ip (in my case: 172.17.0.2) but i get the same error

Comment: Can you list all the adapters associated with the VM in VirtualBox? it would mostly be named `default`. Please tell how many adapters attached and what network type

Comment: I have 3 ethernet adapters (1st - local network, 2nd and 3rd - VirtualBox Host-only) and 4 tunnel-adapter (3 isatap and 1 Turedo-tunneling pseudo interface) with non-reachable state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153570/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-nick-ryan).

Comment: you solved it and didn't write anything. Next time write a solution. Other people can have the same problem